# html/css divs wont auto adjust with screen

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have the textarea boxes align with the photo, and whether they are looking at it from a desktop or cell phone I need the layout to adjust so the boxes don't fall apart from each other. Help please?

html

```
<center>
    <h1>Custom Cut Sizing</h1>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</center>

<div class="center">
    <div class="inline-div"><textarea style="resize: none;" cols="2" id="HeightCC" rows="2" class="leftbox"></textarea></div>
    <div class="inline-div"><img class="img2" src="https://foamtouch.com//wp-content/themes/jshop/cuboid.png"/></div>
        <div class="inline-div"><textarea style="resize: none;" cols="2" id="WidthCC" rows="2" class="rightbox"></textarea></div>
</div>
<center><textarea style="resize: none;" cols="2" id="LengthCC" rows="2"></textarea></center>
Estimated Costs (Including shipping):<p id="Estimated Costs"></p>
<button onclick="CalculateCosts()">Calculate Costs</button>
```

css

```
.center {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 40px;
}

.inline-div {
    display:inline-block;
      height: 10px;
}

.leftbox {
  position: relative;
  top: 19%;
}

.rightbox {
    position: relative;
    top: 0%;
}

.img2{
    width: 550px;   
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: im sorry im new to this website and its my first post would you please explain how i would post my code without it looking junky

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks